# Cast object to superclass / compare only attributes of superclass

Tags: python, inheritance

**What I have:**

I have a class hierarchy of 4 classes that inherit in a chain:

- Superclass A.
- B derives A.
- C derives B.
- D derives C.

Each class has 1 (extra) attribute. So A has 1 attribute, D has 4 attributes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c

class D(C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.d = d
```

**What I want to do:**

I have 2 sets of objects of class D. I want to calculate the intersection of the 2 sets. After that, I want to get the intersection of the remainders of the 2 sets (the sets without the items in the first intersection), but this time comparing them as they were sets of objects of class C (so only comparing 3 of the 4 attributes). And so on...

**The solution?**

<s>In Java I could calculate the intersection of the 2 sets, then cast the remainders of the sets into objects of class C, then calculate the intersection of the 2 sets again to only compare 3 of 4 attributes.
Afaik, there is no type casting like this python.</s> (Not true, as discussed in the comments.)

How do I solve this problem in python? Can I change the class structure somehow to make this possible?

Comment: Just a short notice: you are missing a super()-call in A __init__. It's a common mistake, but if you *would* inherit B from A and a different class F, the buck would stop at A, and not invoke the __init__ of F.

Comment: Okay, thanks for noticing. I am quite new to python and haven't used multiple inheritance so far. Coming from Java :-)

Comment: Comparing two sets of `D` instances is easy enough, but my gut says that the concept of "consider this instance as if it was a member of its parent class" is not a straightforward one.

Comment: I ansewered your question as asked, but in Python such deep inheritance is exceedingly rare. Your problem is most likely better expressed differently.

Comment: Another note: are you *sure* this works in Java the way you describe it? It has been a while for me doing Java, but AFAIK dispatch there is always dynamic. Meaning the hash and equals implementations should be invoked on the actual class, not the super class. Or am I remembering this wrongly?

Comment: I am pretty sure. I would have hash and equals implementations in each class. So after casting the objects to class C, the equals implementation of class C is used, only comparing 3 of 4 attributes.

Comment: I just verified this with a small code example, see https://pastebin.com/3X6bZugi - your assumption is wrong. The dispatch to hashCode from an A-reference still invokes B-hashCode, and it would be breaking a *lot* of code if that weren't the case.

Comment: So, in other words: in Java, you'd have to use a similar approach. Instead of extracting a key as I did into a dataclass (dunno if that concept exists in Java), you could also create a Decorator that would adapt hashCode and equals to type-specific methods. But this would be overkill in python, there you'd simply use the tuple-approach I use. Just one function over dozens of lines of adapter code :)

Comment: You are completely right. I am thinking about which way to go now. I could go your suggested route. Or maybe I could also not take a set of objects of class C or D, but instead just extract the values of the objects and put them into a set, then calculating the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to treat the identities you want to work with as explicit keys to a dictionary mapping this key to your actual object.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c

class D(C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.d = d


def d_key(item):
    return item.a, item.b, item.c, item.d


def c_key(item):
    return item.a, item.b, item.c



a = [D(1, 2, 3, 4), D(1, 3, 2, 4), D(1, 2, 4, 3), D(2, 1, 3, 4)]
b = [D(1, 2, 3, 4), D(1, 3, 2, 4), D(1, 2, 4, 3), D(2, 1, 3, 5)]


ad = dict((d_key(item), item) for item in a)
bd = dict((d_key(item), item) for item in b)

common = ad.keys() & bd.keys()

ac = dict((c_key(item), item) for item in a if d_key(item) in common)
bc = dict((c_key(item), item) for item in b if d_key(item) in common)

print(ac)
print(bc)
```

This approach basically mimics a behaviour where you define a per-class hash/equals or compare Interface.